# How java arguments can be passed to a specific slave in Jenkins?

Tags: java, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, slave

In Jenkins 1580.3 the slave is being launched via execution of a command on the master node like this:

```
ssh jenkins@host "/path/to/java -jar /path/to/slave.jar"
```

What I need to do is set the max heap size to a different value and enable verbose GC logging to a file:

```
ssh jenkins@host "-Xmx6g -verbose:gc -Xloggc:/path/to/GC.lo /path/to/java -jar /path/to/slave.jar"
```

But I get various errors when trying to launch the slave, depending on what first comes in the command:
Unknown mac "xmx6g" for example.
Is there a way to launch a slave with the desired parameters with this launch method?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change :

```
ssh jenkins@host "-Xmx6g -verbose:gc -Xloggc:/path/to/GC.lo /path/to/java -jar /path/to/slave.jar"
```

To :

```
ssh jenkins@host "/path/to/java -Xmx6g -verbose:gc -Xloggc:/path/to/GC.lo  -jar /path/to/slave.jar"
```

Comment: If it worked for you, please accept answer(and upvote if you like)

Comment: In a minute I'll be able to do so. It did work and thanks once more :)